# Django inline admin show child of child

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-inline-models

I have three model in a hierarchy as follows (Django):

```
def A(models.Model):
    pass

def B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)

def C(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

Is it possible in django-admin that I show `C` model as inline of `A` model without using nested-inlines?